# How to use Last inserted id of a Table in Another Table

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server

I have searched and realized i can use SCOPE but am not sure how to use it. Any help will be appreciated

This is Options insert statement

```
char sql[256];
    sprintf_s(sql, "INSERT INTO Options[Value],[ValuesCorrect],[QuestionId]) VALUES ('%s', '%d', '%d'); " 
        , choice->getValue()
        , choice->getIsAnswer()
        , choice->getQuestionId());
        pRecordSet->Open(sql, pConnection.GetInterfacePtr(), adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText);
```

This is my my Question Table

```
char sql[256];
    "DECLARE @ID = BIGINT";
    sprintf_s(sql, "INSERT INTO Questions([Query],[CompetencyLevel],[TopicId]) VALUES('%s', %d, %d); "
        ,(const char*)question->getQuery()
        , question->getCompetencyLevel()
        ,question->getTopicId());
    pRecordSet->Open(sql, pConnection.GetInterfacePtr(), adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText);
    "SELECT@ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return the inserted id

```
INSERT INTO Options (
    [Value]
   ,[ValuesCorrect]
   ,[QuestionId]
) 
OUTPUT inserted.[YourIdColumnName]
VALUES (
   '%s'
  ,'%d'
  ,'%d'
)
```

A long time since I used ADO but the code could look something like

```
pRecordSet->Open(...);
auto id = pRecordSet->Fields->Item[0]->Value;
```

Comment: I have figured it. But Thanks Anyway